# Django Rest Framework Serializer Update Method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer that I am using to make an update I however cannot seem to make it work. The view is a ModelViewSet, and the main Model is a User model which has a foreign key mapping to a Profile model. Below is the view code

```
class RegisterPublicAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # serializer_class = RegisterPublicSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
    lookup_field = "public_id"
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ['list', 'retrieve']:
            return RegisterListPublicSerializer
        if self.action == 'create':
            return RegisterManagePublicSerializer
        else:
            return RegisterUpdatePublicSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.all()

    def post(self, request):
        updateSerializers = self.get_serializer_class()
        serializer = updateSerializers(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        user_data = serializer.data
        return Response(user_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Below is the serializer code with comments on what I have tried and the error response I am getting.

```
class RegisterUpdatePublicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    department = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    salutation = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, required=True)
    firstname = serializers.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)
    lastname = serializers.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)
    mobile = serializers.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)
    tel = serializers.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ('id',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile = Profile.objects.get(id=instance.profile.id)
        profile.firstname = validated_data.get('firstname')
        profile.lastname = validated_data.get('lastname')
        profile.mobile = validated_data.get('mobile')
        profile.tel = validated_data.get('tel')
        profile.salutation = validated_data.get('salutation')
        profile.save()
        dept = Department.objects.get(id=validated_data.get('department'))
        # instance.department_id = (dept.id, instance.department_id)  # Expected a number but got (2, 2)
        # instance.department_id = dept.id  # TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Department'
        instance.department_id = dept  # TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <Department: Marketing>
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

What have I missed?

**EDIT**

I updated my serializer to the one below, the problem was when returning the instance, the update was always successful but failed on return somehow.

```
class RegisterUpdatePublicSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    department = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    salutation = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, required=True)
    firstname = serializers.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)
    lastname = serializers.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)
    mobile = serializers.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)
    tel = serializers.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        dept = Department.objects.get(id=validated_data.get('department'))

        profile = Profile.objects.get(id=instance.profile.id)
        profile.salutation = validated_data.pop('salutation')
        profile.firstname = validated_data.pop('firstname')
        profile.lastname = validated_data.pop('lastname')
        profile.mobile = validated_data.pop('mobile')
        profile.tel = validated_data.pop('tel')
        profile.save()
        instance.department = dept
        instance.save()
        return {
            'email': instance.email,
            'username': instance.username,
            'salutation': profile.salutation,
            'department': dept.id,
            'firstname': profile.firstname,
            'lastname': profile.lastname,
            'mobile': profile.mobile,
            'tel': profile.tel,
        }
```